# Get exit status of last command in Python script

Tags: python

How can I get the exist status (if command succeed or not) of any line in Python?

For example in bash, `$?` will tell me the last exist status of any command.
I need it to know if my connection to FTP server was successful or not.

Comment: No, there's no such concept. All you can get is the return value from a function. How are you connecting to the FTP server? Are you using [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib)? Also, add your code.

Comment: Python is not Bash. Calling functions or methods of classes does not cause an exit status to be set. It may return a value or throw an exception. But there is nothing like `$?` in Bash. If you want to use [`ftplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html), read the documentation. There are various exceptions described there.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. and yes, i use ftplib

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a `try/catch`? If there was an error while executing the command, an exception will be raised. You can retrieve it with the [sys](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html) module.

Example code:

```
import sys 

try:
    run_command()
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a function you call, it should have a retrun code you can collect like

```
retVal = doSomething()
```

Then you can check what happened.